# Parse Cells in Spreadsheet and get Geometric mean

Tags: split, google-sheets, worksheet-function, array-formulas

I have a google spreadsheet with entries like this:

```
| 102584 (46.93%) | 15561 (7.12%) | 15709 (7.19%) | 33358 (15.26%) 

| 102522 (46.90%) | 15561 (7.12%) | 15709 (7.19%) | 33358 (15.26%)
```

I want to grab the raw numbers beside the parentheses across a whole row and get the geometric mean for that row.  What I have right now is:

```
=geomean(arrayformula(index(split(G3:AQ3,"()"),0,1)))
```

So I try to `split` each cell by parentheses, `index` into the first element in the parsed array, operate on the whole range as an array with `arrayformulta` (otherwise it seems to add the raw number to the raw percent), and then get the `geomean`.  But this seems to only work on the first cell of the range.  If I tried operating on a column instead of a row, it seems to work, but I can't get the operations to work on a row for some reason.  Is there any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole splitting doesn't really work, try this instead

```
=GEOMEAN(ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(A3:D3, "^[0-9]+") + 0))
```

Comment: Regexextract will extract strings, adding 0 will coerce them into numbers of which we can take the geometric mean

Comment: If this solved your problem please accept the answer so other people can find it

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I should have just searched for regex extraction to begin with, much easier and more intuitive.

Is it possible to do a getOrElse on regexextract to ignore cells that are blank?

Comment: I think for this purpose you'll have to wrap it into `IF(LEN(extraction), extraction+0, "")` to keep blanks blanks and not add 0

Comment: I finally got it to do what I wanted after lots of building up and code substitution with the final, verbose formula:

`=geomean(ARRAYFORMULA(if(not(arrayformula(len(arrayformula(if(len(G3:AS3)=0, "", REGEXEXTRACT(G3:AS3,"^[0-9]+"))))=0)), value(trim(arrayformula(if(len(G3:AS3)=0, "", REGEXEXTRACT(G3:AS3,"^[0-9]+"))))))))`

Answer (score 1):

```
=GEOMEAN(INDEX(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(A1:C1),"("),,1))
```

- `SPLIT` doesn't work across columns. So, `TRANSPOSE` it.
- You can't `SPLIT` by both `()`. `SPLIT` by the first `(` to SPLIT it into `102584` and `46.93%)`
- `ARRAYFORMULA` isn't explicitly needed.